# Scala: Refined Algebraic Data Types

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

o/

This might be a rather interesting question, and one that might spark some creativity among you.

I want to model currencies in a way that I can:

- pattern match over the type (=> algebraic data type)
- store a numeric amount in it
- use a [refined type](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) for constraining the value to e.g. positive values, like `val amount: Float Refined Positive`
- have a three character currency code like "USD" that is predefined and immutable

Doing a subset of this in one implementation is easy, but I found it surprisingly hard to create a type that allows for something like the following:

```
def doSomething(currency: Currency): Unit {
  currency match {
    case BITCOIN => println("Oh, a cryptocurrency! And it is ${currency.amount} ${currency.code}!"
    case EURO => println("So we are from Europe, eh?")
  }
}

doSomething(new Currency.BITCOIN(123f)) // yielding "Oh, a cryptocurrency! And it is 123 BTC!"

val euro = new Currency.EURO(-42f) // compile error
```

I hope I made my intentions clear. If there is a library doing that, I'm happy to be pointed at it, though I hope to learn something from thinking about this myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined
import eu.timepit.refined.auto._
import eu.timepit.refined.numeric.NonNegative
import eu.timepit.refined.string.MatchesRegex

sealed trait Currency extends Product with Serializable {
  def amount: Currency.Amount
  def code: Currency.Code
}

object Currency {
  type Amount = BigDecimal Refined NonNegative
  type Code = String Refined MatchesRegex["[A-Z]{3}"]

  final case class Euro(amount: Amount) extends Currency {
    override final val code: Code = "EUR"
  }

  final case class Dollar(amount: Amount) extends Currency {
    override final val code: Code = "USD"
  }
}

def doSomething(currency: Currency): Unit =
  currency match {
    case Currency.Euro(amount) => println(s"Euro: € ${amount}")
    case _ => println(s"Somenthing else with code ${currency.code} and amount ${currency.amount}")
  }
```

This works:

```
doSomething(Currency.Dollar(BigDecimal(10))) 
// Somenthing else with code USD and amount 10
```

Comment: This looks great! The compiler also issues the warning I wanted in case of incomplete matching branches. I just could not figure out how to combine a trait, an object etc. with the refined types. I'm very happy from this point of view. It only remains an old friend of a compiler warning, which complains about the final inner case classes. Do you know any way around that, other than not setting the case classes to final?

Comment: Hm, there are also problems when trying to instantiate a currency from another package, because the inner types can not be referenced. :/

Comment: @Aarkon For me the code doesn't produce any warnings. Also, all types are public so with a correct import they should be accessible. Maybe you are putting this on  a `package object`?

Comment: Nope, just using your design and testing it in a plain ScalaTest. Either the constructor for the refined type can not be accessed or the compiler sees a type error when applying BigDecimal to Amount (maybe it's the same reason). Which Scala version are you on?

Comment: @Aarkon `2.13.1` it should work, see [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/3k1C7npvTAe8EoKMyRZocQ/1). One note, you need `import eu.timepit.refined.auto._` everywhere when you want to build an instance of **Amount**.